# Reporting product fulfillment with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, fulfillment

My WP8 app has an in-app purchase for a consumable item. It's my understanding that you must report the fulfillment of the product to the marketplace upon delivery of the item.

So my question is, what happens if I can't? If there's no internet connection for example.

Any example code I've seen retrieve the product listing, then call `RequestProductPurchaseAsync` and then straight after `ReportProductFulfillment`

Basically I want both to succeed or neither... If `RequestProductPurchaseAsync` succeeds does that mean the customer is charged, even if I don't report the fulfillment?

Or should I be checking `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation` for the relevant license, and if `IsActive` is true then I'm safe to assume that the purchase was successful and then I should report fulfillment. But I need a way of knowing if the fulfillment was successful too so I can try again if need be.

Hope this makes some sense, if anyone has any ideas or can point me in the direction of some material to read I'd much appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it:

If there is no network, u won't even proceed to purchase experience or user cancels the purchase RequestProductPurchaseAsync will throw exception which you should catch it and handle it appropriately. Fulfillment should be done immediately if user purchased the item.

```
await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(productId, false);
if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[productId].IsActive)
{
     // Report fulfillment
     CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(productId);
     ------------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check if the license `IsActive` what you could do is:

```
PurchaseResults receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(pID);
string status = receipt.Status.ToString();
if(status == "succeeded")
{
 // do your stuff
}
```